# Thermoelectric Generator Impedance Matching

Tags: voltage-regulator, impedance-matching, peltier

I have a TEG that has an output IxV curve like this:
[image]

That should mean something like this:

[image]

I need a simple circuit to regulate the voltage around 12 V while enabling at least  ~10 W for some load I have (0,833 A)

My idea was to use a simple zener diode, a capacitor and a voltage regulator for the 12 V output

[image]

What do you think? for R1 I thought about 5-30 ohm,  for Zn1 30 Vbkd and C1 ~ 0,00001 F.

Do you have any comments about the layout or values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a buck converter. Max power you can get (from that graph) is 48V 0.33A or a shade over 16W. The buck can translate this to 12V at about 1.3A.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of R1, it wastes power.

Get rid of the 7812, it wastes power.

Get rid of ZN1, it may waste power.

Replace the regulator with a switching 12 V output regulator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought about this, but could not find any converter to handle the 100 V max input, at least where I live. What would happen if I connect two buck converters in series?